# VBA: loop to create command buttons for every cell in a range with .OnAction procedure calling with cell-specific parameters

Tags: string, vba, button, parameters, arguments

I need help writing some a loop to create a command button for every cell in a range.
I achieved creating as many buttons as I need. my problem is setting the .OnAction property for each of them.
Every button will send an email through Lotus Notes to a specified address, with subject and body of the mail stored in adjacent cells. That code already works, here it is the procedure to send the email:

```
Sub Send(ByVal MailAddress, Subject, Message As String)

Dim Maildb As Object
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim Body As Object
Dim Session As Object

    Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
    Call Session.Initialize
    'Call Session.Initialize("password")
    UserName = Session.UserName
    Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("", "C:\Lotus\Notes\Data\names.nsf")
    'Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName)
    If Not Maildb.IsOpen = True Then Call Maildb.Open
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo")
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", MailAddress)
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", Subject)
    Set Body = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
    Call Body.AppendText(Message)
    MailDoc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("PostedDate", Now())
    Call MailDoc.Send(False)

    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set Body = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to create the buttons when the workbook opens, iterating through the first compiled column of my sheet. Next, I'll add/delete buttons when adding/deleting rows to the sheets. To do so I have at the moment the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim L As Integer
   Dim t As Range
   Dim btn As Button
   Dim arg As String

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
   Sheets(1).Activate
   L = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C"))
   For i = 2 To L
        Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1))
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top + 5, t.Width, 20)
        'arg = "'Invia  Range("J1").Value , Cells(i, t.Column + 2).Value , Cells(i, t.Column+3).Value '"
        With btn
           .OnAction = arg
           .Caption = "Invia"
           .Name = "Btn" & i
        End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

My problem is I'm not able to write the string to pass to OnAction property in the correct way.
That should be the call to procedure Send with 3 parameters:
1) MailAddress: found in cell J1 (static)
2) Subject: found in columns C at the current row (i) of the loop
3) Body: found in column D at the current row (i) of the loop

Can't get it to work.
I'm quite new to VBA and I'm getting crazy with all those quotes, single quotes and double quotes.
May someone kindly help me?
Mhanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: It's easier to grab the name of the button in the OnAction sub (using `Application.Caller`) and then use that to determine what action to take. In this case you can parse out the value of `i` and just get the needed info from the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks, that was the tip I was looking for. worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

```
arg = "'Send ""{1}"", ""{2}"", ""{3}"" '" 

arg = Replace(arg,"{1}", Range("J1").Value)
arg = Replace(arg,"{2}", Cells(i, t.Column + 2).Value)
arg = Replace(arg,"{3}", Cells(i, t.Column+3).Value)

.OnAction = arg
```

Comment: This should be the generally accepted answer. It shows how the use of the single ' character makes a difficult thing possible